# Gradient of a function at the boundary of a constant region

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Seemingly an easy thing to do, I had difficulty to find an answer for the following: Let's assume we have a function $f(x)$ which is defined as $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$. The function has continuous partial derivatives everywhere. Let's assume that this function has constant value ("plateau") in a closed and bounded region $A$. Assume $\partial A$ as the boundary of $A$ and consider a point $x' \in \partial A$. Then what can we say about the gradient $\nabla f(x')$? Does it vanish? My intuition tells that this is true: My "sketch" of a possible proof involves first selecting $n$ linearly independent vectors at $x'$, ($n$ is the dimension of the domain, $\mathbb{R^n}$) which points "into" the the region $A$. By "into", I imply a tangent hyperplane to $A$ at $x'$, with its normal $w$ oriented away from $A$ and selecting vectors $v_i$ such that $w^Tv_i < 0$. Then, the directional derivatives $v_i^T \nabla f(x')=0$ for all $v_i$ since they are pointing into the region of constant value for $f$. Then I build a $n \times n$ matrix $V$ with each of its rows set to vectors $v_i$. It is then $V\nabla f(x') = 0$. Since all the rows are linearly independent, the matrix is full rank and therefore it must be $\nabla f(x')=0$.

Now, there are two things which are not very rigorous here: 1)The fact that I set a tangent hyperplane with normal $w$ for $A$ passing through $x'$ and 2) I arbitrarily selected $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_i$ such that $w^Tv_i < 0$.

Is my argument correct here? What would be a rigorous way to prove or disprove that statement?

Comment: Seems to me that if $\partial A$ is a smooth $n-1$ dimensional submanifold, your idea works, for the reasons you give.

Comment: It really depends on $A$. For example, if $A$ is just a point, or contained in some proper subspace, it says nothing about the gradient of $f$ at that point. Perhaps if $A$ was equal to the closure of its interior, or something like that?

Comment: By closure of the interior, do you mean that union of $A$'s interior and its boundary $\partial A$ is that right? If that is right, we can say that it is so: $A$ is such a region.